# Merging by id correctly but get empty object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that needs to be merged by id (sourceID), which seems to be done, but both imagesTest objects return empty. Now sure what I am doing wrong here?

My code looks like this:

```js
const eventsToBeInserted1 = [{
    name: 'Katy Perry',
    slug: 'katy-perry',
    sourceID: [1],
    tags: ['music', 'jazz'],
    images1: ['picture_perry_1', 'picture_perry_2']
  },
  {
    name: 'Lukas Graham',
    slug: 'lukas-graham',
    sourceID: [2],
    tags: ['rock', 'techno'],
    images1: ['picture_graham_1', 'picture_graham_2']
  }
]

const imagesTest = [{
    sourceID: 1,
    images: ['picture_perry.jpg']
  },
  {
    sourceID: 2,
    images: ['picture_graham.jpg']
  }
]

const eventsToBeInserted = eventsToBeInserted1.map(
  event => Object.assign({}, event, {
    imagesTest: imagesTest
      .filter(img => img.sourceID === event.sourceID)
      .map(img => img.name)
  }))

console.log(eventsToBeInserted)
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. The concept of merging implies that there are multiple records you are reducing into a single record, however, that doesn't seem to be the case here. Is sourceID unique? Or is it actually a 1:1 relationship and you're just trying to map your data?

Comment: wanted to vote down because Katy Perry is tagged 'jazz' (just joking, didn't vote)

Comment: Theres no img.name ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `eventsToBeInserted1` the `sourceId` is defined as an array: `sourceID: [1]`.

Either change it to be defined as a regular int: `sourceID: 1`

or change the merge function:

```
const eventsToBeInserted = eventsToBeInserted1.map(
  event => Object.assign({}, event, {
    imagesTest: imagesTest
      .filter(img => img.sourceID === event.sourceID[0])
      .map(img => img.name)
  }))
```

Comment: If I understand the question I think you'll also want `.map(img => event.name)`

Comment: Additionaly, if there might be multiple sources it would be event.sourceId.indexOf(img.sourceId) ...

Comment: Using the above and changing it to `.map(img => event.name)` got the job done. Thanks for the help @fatman and @Mark_M - really appreciate it!